# Remove / (forward slash) from date string in Jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I am trying to remove a forward slash from a date string.

The date is currently in the format dd/mm/yyyy but i need to remove / and replace with -, so its dd-mm-yyyy

I've tried lots of things, along these lines:

```
var from = $('#from_date').text().replace(/\//g, '-');

var from_pre = $('#from_date').val();
var from = from_pre.text().replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: What type of element `$("#from_date")`? Your first one should work fine, I'm just worried that you're using `.text()` on an input or something.

Comment: Its a date field, posted as a string

Comment: Then just replace `.text()` in your first one with `.val()` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `text` on the value

```
var from = $('#from_date').val().replace(/\//g, '-')
```